# How to reverse improper .less class, which uses the ":not"-selector

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, less

I'm stuggeling with a .less problem, where a rule is applied to nearly all elements of my web application using the :not-sector. A collegue applied the following rule:

```
:not(.expanded) {
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

As you might notice: All elements, which do not have the `.expanded`-Class will be animated. Originally the rule should have been applied for a special .css-Class and it's subclasses and of course not to all elements using this very unspecific rule.
Nevertheless: A new release will take some time, so I can not wait for the next release.
Now I'm trying to reverse the less rule, which could be easy using the following:

```
:not(.expanded) {
    animation: none !important;
}
```

This works flawlessly - too flawlessly. No animation is performed as all animations are set to "none". Of course this is not my goal, since other elements should be animated.

Is there any clever way to fix my problem?
I'm open for every option using .css, less or JavaScript (including the Dojo-Framework).

Comment: *No animation is performed as all animations are set to "none". Of course this is not my goal, since other elements should be animated.* - So what are elements that should be animated? Do they have a class (or) are they of a certain element type?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've updated my question since I've made a stupid copy&paste mistake.

Comment: That's ok. The second comment (now the first) is still applicable. It would be much better if you include your HTML also in code (and indicate which should and which should not get the animation). It is much better than shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Harry Regarding your last comment. The elements, which should be animated, have special classes, but it would not be easy to identify all of these...some are created dynamically.

Comment: Well, they should have something in common and something that is known (like an id or a class or an element type something). If they have none (or) if you don't know them then `:not()` is the only option as far as I know using CSS/Less. You may want to look at using JS + inline styles to apply the animation only to the elements that need it. Inline styles will override any CSS.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the information. I'll look into the inline-syles part.